# Mandrill sending to multiple people as separate message via the REST API

Tags: rest, mandrill

I'm trying to send out mails using mandrill. The problem is that when I add multiple recipients to the 'to' parameter, it sends out the same mail multiple times with ALL the recepients in the 'to' list. I was expecting the same mail to be sent out individually to every person in the to list. Am I missing something ?

```
{
    "key": "app-key",
    "template_name": "platform-invite",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "connection",
            "content": "<a class=\"mcnButton \" title=\"Lets Go\" href=\"http://someurl\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;\">Lets go</a>"
        },
        {
            "name": "mailbody",
            "content": "<p>Hi </p>\n<p>I would like you to be a ... Tic tic tic...</p>"
        }
    ],
    "message": {
        "subject": "My subject line over herer",
        "from_email": "superman@mydomain.co",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "person1@gmail.com,
                "type": "to"
            },
            {
                "email": "person2@gmail.com",
                "type": "to"
            },
            {
                "email": "person3@gmail.com",
                "type": "to"
            },
            {
                "email": "person4@gmail.com",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": {}
    },
    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": "Main Pool"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an option in your [Sending Options](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options) to expose recipients to one another. You can uncheck that box to not show everyone's information in the 'to' header. The option(s) you select in the Sending Options are used by default for your account. You can override any of these options in individual API calls. In this case, you could use the `preserve_recipients` parameter to override the current default that's set for your account.

Comment: that's exactly what it was. appreciate the quick reply

Comment: Please show php example. its not helping with string or descriptions.

Comment: Ugh just exposed our list of emails. Seems like this should be off by default :-(